# Setup a cron for multiple commands in a single line

Tags: unix, cron

I execute a sh file using command `./abc.sh abc_config`

How do we get this done via cron ? for a single command i usually do

`5 0 * * * /test/abc.sh`

But for `./abc.sh abc_config` I am a little confused

Comment: Do you mean multiple commands or just a command with a parameter like in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to store the script and it's argument in another script and run that instead?

```
5 0 * * * /test/run_abc.sh
```

Contents of `run_abc.sh`

```
./abc.sh abc_config
```

You should possibly include paths and a "shebang" matching whatever shell you want to use, ie:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/path-to-dir-where-program-is/abc.sh abc_config
```

Comment: I think crontab - e should do that for you easily.

Comment: The other thing to check would be the path -- in the working /test/abc.sh example, that's a fully resolved path where ./abc.sh is not. From [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/337631/crontab-execution-doesnt-have-the-same-environment-variables-as-executing-user):

> Cron always runs with a mostly empty environment. HOME, LOGNAME, and SHELL are set; and a very limited PATH. It is therefore advisable to use complete paths to executables, and export any variables you need in your script when using cron.